# Flex 4 Drop Down List - bound with data service, how to always keep prompt or add item at index -1 programmatically

Tags: null, drop-down-menu, flex4, prompt, databound-controls

I have a drop down list that is bound using an HTTP data service from a database (set up through the wizard, not as a declaration). My drop down list changes the values in my datagrid and I need that "Select One" null value so that users can select everything. Here is my drop down list:

```
<s:DropDownList id="ddlProducts" width="400" prompt="Select a Product" close="dataGridContentChanging()" creationComplete="ddlProducts_creationCompleteHandler(event)" labelField="Title">  
    <s:dataProvider>  
        <s:AsyncListView list="{GetProductsResult.lastResult}"/>  
   </s:dataProvider>  
</s:DropDownList>
```

Is there a way to always keep the prompt or to programmatically add a "Select One" to the -1 index of the drop down list?

Any help is apprecitated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

setup an all value in ur Database
  (any number of ways to do: this
 if you are using a look up table just add it to the table, if 
you are pulling from your data table put in a union statement)

then handle the the 'All' value (on click) to put in '%' as ur variable in dataprovider